# RabbitMQ loadbalancing and failover with ipvsadm LVS

Tags: java, rabbitmq, cluster-computing, failover

We have a plateform that uses 2 rabbitmq nodes loadbalanced by a linux LVS (ipvsadm) in front. We have ipvsadm configured with persistent connections and clients with heartbeat. So far so good.

After deployment, we generally have half of the clients connected to the first node and the other half connected to the second node. 
We tried to stop one node (rabbitmqctl stop_app and start_app). The clients are reconnecting rabbitmq cluster, and the LVS sends the connections to the node up. So all the clients are connected to the second node.

We have 2 questions :

1) when the first node is up, how do you manage to reconnect the clients on the two nodes (loadbalancing) ?

2) is it a problem if all the clients are connected to one node ?

Thank you for your anwsers.